# unable to fetch data from skybiometry

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch `tid` of a photo from [SkyBiometry](https://skybiometry.com) in a callback function as shown below, but it doesn't work.

```
function callback(data) {
      drawFaces($("#conent_demo_image"), data.photos[0], true);
      var tid = data.photos[0].tags[0].tid;

      $("#tid").text(tid);
    }
```

The html:

```
<div id="tid">
  tid:   
</div>
```

Comment: You can show the value of the `data`?

Comment: @Valentin Thanks for your response, I have found the solution with jquery getJSON method

Comment: You haven't shown how the `callback` function is (or should be) invoked nor given enough explanation of _why_ it doesn't work for you. If you've found the solution yourself I'd suggest you either post it as an answer or that this question should be closed if it isn't made more complete.

Answer (score 3):

According to the source of [SkyBiometry Demo](https://www.skybiometry.com/demo) it should be something like this:

```
{
  "RawData": "...",
  "Status": 0,
  "photos": [{
    "url": "https://skybiometry.com/Content/Samples/one_i.jpg",
    "pid": "F@0ae0deaf6994b85e751943ae2166ec27_24412177fed2f",
    "width": 480,
    "height": 480,
    "tags": [{
      "tid": "TEMP_F@0ae0deaf6994b85e751943ae012b00ab_24412177fed2f_62.29_35.62_0_1",
      "recognizable": true,
      "uids": [],
      "label": null,
      "confirmed": false,
      "manual": false,
      "width": 20.83,
      "height": 20.83,
      "center": {"x": 62.29, "y": 35.62},
      "eye_left": {"x": 68.54, "y": 30.42, "confidence": 57, "id": 449},
      "eye_right": {"x": 56.67, "y": 30.42, "confidence": 55, "id": 450},
      "mouth_center": {"x": 62.5, "y": 42.92, "confidence": 54, "id": 615},
      "nose": {"x": 63.33, "y": 37.71, "confidence": 51, "id": 403},
      "yaw": -6.0,
      "roll": -1.0,
      "pitch": 0.0,
      "attributes": {
        "face": {"value": true, "confidence": 70},
        "gender": {"Value": 1, "value": "female", "confidence": 75},
        "glasses": {"value": false, "confidence": 81},
        "dark_glasses": {"value": false, "confidence": 58},
        "smiling": {"value": true, "confidence": 100},
        "age_est": {"value": 16, "confidence": 50},
        "mood": {"Value": 2, "value": "happy", "confidence": 76},
        "lips": {"Value": 1, "value": "parted", "confidence": 100},
        "eyes": {"Value": 0, "value": "open", "confidence": 87},
        "neutral_mood": {"value": false, "confidence": 0},
        "anger": {"value": false, "confidence": 45},
        "disgust": {"value": false, "confidence": 1},
        "fear": {"value": false, "confidence": 0},
        "happiness": {"value": true, "confidence": 76},
        "sadness": {"value": false, "confidence": 2},
        "surprise": {"value": false, "confidence": 6}
      },
      "points": null,
      "similarities": null
    }]
  }],
  "status": "success",
  "usage": {
    "ResetTime": "2015-11-07T20:02:54Z",
    "used": 21633,
    "reset_time_text": "Sat, 7 November 2015 20:02:54 +0000",
    "remaining": 78367,
    "namespace_used": 0,
    "limit": 100000,
    "namespace_remaining": 0,
    "reset_time": 1446926574,
    "namespace_limit": 0
  },
  "operation_id": "c869d8e95f364f979dd62277810b299c"
}
```